# Create a counter that only counts a certain logical value and gives the same number to repetitions

Tags: r, dplyr, datatable, counter, data-cleaning

Say I have a logical value like this

```
rex <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, NA)
```

How do I create a counter which will only count for the `TRUE` and will group consecutive repetitions as the same value in the counter. ex. to have something like this:

```
1, NA, 2,2,NA, 3, NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted solution doesn't work for the following case:

```
rex <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, NA, NA, TRUE)
```

It prints `1 NA  2  2 NA  3 NA NA NA`.

The following function returns the correct answer:

```
solution <- function (rex) {
  result <- c()
  counter <- 1
  consecutive <- FALSE
  for (i in 1:length(rex)) {
    if (rex[i] == TRUE && !is.na(rex[i]) && consecutive) {
      result <- c(result, counter)
      consecutive <- TRUE
    } else if (rex[i] == TRUE && !is.na(rex[i]) && !consecutive) {
      result <- c(result, counter)
      consecutive <- TRUE
    } else{
      if(i < length(rex) && rex[i+1] == TRUE && !is.na(rex[i+1])){
        counter <- counter + 1
      }
      result <- c(result, NA)
      consecutive <- FALSE
    }
  }
  return(result)
}
```

Calling `solution(rex)` prints `1 NA  2  2 NA  3 NA NA  4`, which is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `rle` and its inverse:

```
 inverse.rle(modifyList(b<-rle(rex),list(values = with(b,cumsum(values)*NA^(!values)))))
[1]  1 NA  2  2 NA  3 NA
```

This can also be written as:

```
inverse.rle(`[[<-`(b<-rle(rex),"values",with(b,cumsum(values)*NA^(!values))))
```

To break it down:

```
b <- rle(rex)
b$values <- cumsum(b$values) * NA^(!b$values)
inverse.rle(b)
```

Comment: What about `rex = c(NA, TRUE, FALSE)`?

Comment: @Henrik good question In that case, just use `b <- rle(rex & !is.na(rex))`

Comment: @HelioCuve That is a completely different question. Please consider asking it. In that case, many will give you ways on how to go about it. You could come back here and paste the link to that new question.

Comment: thanks @Onyambu, just deleted the comment, her is the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62412349/how-to-create-a-counter-that-groups-repeats-into-the-same-value-while-ignoring-n

Answer (score 0):

A twist on the answer provided by @Onyambu could be:

```
with(rle(!is.na(rex) & rex), rep(cumsum(values), lengths)) * rex^NA

[1]  1 NA  2  2 NA  3 NA
```

It should also work when there are NAs not just at the end of the vector.