# How to create a counter that groups repeats into the same value while ignoring NAs

Tags: r

I dataframe with more than 5000 rows of a simulation. My problem is like this

```
rex <- c("Positive", "Negative", NA, "Positive", "Negative", "Negative")
```

I would like to create a counter that returns:

```
1,2,NA,3,4,4
```

as the result, where the repetition of the same value, has the same counter.

Appreciate any help. Thank you,

Best

Comment: should `rex <- c("Positive", NA, "Positive")` result in `1, NA, 1` or `1, NA, 2`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here we could make use of `data.table::rleid` eg

```
library(data.table)
rex <- c("Positive", "Negative", NA, "Positive", "Negative", "Negative",NA,"Negative")
idx <- !is.na(rex)
```

if `rex <- c("Positive", NA, "Positive")` should output  `1, NA, 1`

```
as.numeric(replace(rex, idx, rleid(rex[idx])))
[1]  1  2 NA  3  4  4 NA  4
```

if `rex <- c("Positive", NA, "Positive")` should output  `1, NA, 2`

```
as.numeric(replace(rex, idx, rleid(rleid(rex)[idx])))
[1]  1  2 NA  3  4  4 NA  5
```